# Eclipse: use both tabs and spaces for indentation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, indentation

A project I'm working in has an indentation standard as follows:

- A single tab-width is 4 space characters.
- A double tab-width is a tab character displayed at 8 spaces wide.

Examples:

- A singly-indented line begins with four spaces
- A doubly-indented line begins with a tab character
- A triply-indented line begins with a tab character followed by four spaces
- A 4x indented line begins with two tab characters
- ...and so on

In Vim, the necessary configuration is achieved with:

```
:set tabstop=8 softtabstop=4 noexpandtab
```

How can I configure Eclipse to automatically enforce this indentation standard?

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Editors > Text Editors_ you can set the _Display tab width_ and enable or disable _Insert spaces for tabs_. Can you give an example where these settings are not enough for you?

Comment: @howlger: I gave a thorough example in the question's body. I'm not certain what more I can offer, but I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does support this natively.

**My eclipse version:**
[image: My Eclipse version]

**The result (see in-image comments):**
 [image: The result]

**Step 1:**
[image: 1]

**Step 2:**
[image: 2]

**Step 3:**
 [image: 3]

**Step 4 (the most important step):**
  [image: 4]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Eclipse CDT supports this indentation style.

Eclipse is open source; you could consider [contributing a patch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development) to add support for this style.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't have that built-in, but it looks like the plug-in **[Vrapper (Vim)](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/vrapper-vim)** provides what you are looking for.

See [Vrapper > Documentation > Configuration](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/documentation/?topic=configuration):

> - **softtabstop** - When using spaces for tabs, set this to the number of spaces inserted for each <kbd>Tab</kbd> key press and hitting
>     <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in InsertMode will delete that many spaces as if you had
>     deleted a tab character.
> - **tabstop** - Used by `i_ctrl-t`, `i_ctrl-d`, and `:retab`. Determines number of spaces to replace each tab character with when `xpandtab` is enabled.
> - **expandtab/noexpandtab** - Used by `i_ctrl-t`, `i_ctrl-d`, and `:retab`. Determines whether `:retab` should replace all tabs with spaces (true) or spaces with tabs (false). Also determines whether `i_ctrl-t` and `i_ctrl-d` will replace `tabstop` spaces with a tab.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this plugin. Unfortunately, "softtabstop" has no effect with "noexpandtab" set. This is hinted at in the text you quoted: "softtabstop - When using spaces for tabs, ..."

Comment: [There are more Vim plug-ins available.](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/vim). Maybe you'll find it there. If not, you can send a feature request to the plug-in that came closest to your needs.